# Display first and last names first letters in a div with only one input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a text input where you can write your first name and your last name. The first letter of the first name and surname should be displayed in a DIV. The letters should be displayed directly without clicking a button.

**For example:**

You write "John Doe" in the text field and JD should be displayed in the DIV.

**In the end it should look like this**:
[image: In the end it should look like this]

Comment: What problem are you facing in particular? You'll just split the string by space " " and get the first letter of the the words and set them as the divs text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
let text = ''
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", () => {
  text = document.querySelector("input").value;

  let full_name = text.split(" ");
  let initials = full_name[0][0];
  if (text) {
    if (full_name.length >= 2 && full_name[1]) {
      initials += full_name[1][0];
    }
  } else {
    initials = '';
  }


  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = initials;


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
  <input type="text">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to put the letters in a div and it should show the text without clicking on a button?

Comment: I modified it based on what you suggested. Essentially you need to listen on change and then update accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I realised that if you delete the text again, it will say "undefined". Do you know how to remove this? I am very sorry, I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: I made new modifications to the answer. To check for undefined in the received text you can use a simple if statement like: `if(text)`. Checkout java script snippet for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
const extractFirstLetters = function(name) {
  let firstName = name.split(' ')[0];
  let lastName = name.split(' ')[1];

  let firstLetters = firstName[0] + lastName[0];

  return firstLetters;
}

let output = extractFirstLetters("John Doe")

// Output => "JD"
```

Proceed to set `div.innerHTML = output`.

More on [JS DOM Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:-

1 - Text way

```js
const val = document.getElementById('name').value;
document.getElementById('initials').innerHTML = val.split[" "][0] + val.split[" "][1]
```

```html
<div id="initials"><div>
<input type="text" id="name" value="John Doe">
```

2 - Image way

Using API to generate an image of the initials,

https://ui-avatars.com/

And set the image as the background of the `initials` div.